# Is it possible to make use of the --custom-package flag from IntelliJ?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

`aapt` appears to have a `--custom-package` flag. Is it possible to configure the Android facet of IntelliJ such that it is possible to make use of this flag? Looking at the Project Structure GUI, I get the impression that it is not.

Though I do see that `CUSTOM_COMPILER_MANIFEST` is listed in the `.iml` file, but I do not see how that bubbles up into the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported at the moment, please [vote for this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-71391).